# Creating an NSError Domain

Tags: iphone, ios, nserror

I would like to create a custom error domain for my application. I have an enumerated `NSInteger` type that covers all possible error codes I can get, my question is how do I associate these with my custom domain? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your domain is just a string naming it. You don't need to register it anywhere.

In your header with your error codes, add this line:

```
extern NSString *const MyErrorDomain;
```

And in your implementation file:

```
NSString *const MyErrorDomain = @"MyErrorDomain";
```

Then you can use that named constant for your error domain. Done!

Comment: Just to clarify when you say implementation file where would the best place for this be? I am creating a custom error class. MyError.

Comment: However, the best would be to use an inverse url scheme, e.g. `com.mycompany.myapp.error`. If you want to use it only in one custom error, place the definition inside the MyError.m file, not accessible from outside.

Comment: @MarioPen: Your `.m` file. If you don't have one that matches the header where your `enum` is, best practice would be to make one and put the constant there.

Comment: @Sulthan Reverse notation isn't usually used for error domains because they can be presented to users, and the notation usually makes them very long. It's all a matter of style/preference though, as any string will be treated as a valid error domain.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan Error domain is not something that should be presented to users. Never. The format is recommended in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorObjectsDomains/ErrorObjectsDomains.html

Comment: @Sulthan: There are legitimate reasons to present an error code to the user, and when doing so on a Mac you need to present the domain as well (otherwise, error code -1 or 400 or 25 could mean anything.)